# Unable to work with PowerCLI commands in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, powercli

I want to use PowerCLI cmdlets in my C# code.When I add-pssnapin to my powershell object and then execute command from this snap-in it raises a exception.

this is part of my code:

```
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VMware.Vim;
using VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets;
using VMware.ImageBuilder;
using VMware.ImageBuilder.Commands;
namespace EsxImageBuilder

class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        using (Runspace runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfig))
        {
            runSpace.Open();
            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                powerShell.Runspace = runSpace;
                powerShell.Commands.AddCommand("Add-PSSnapin").AddArgument("VMware.ImageBuilder");
                powerShell.Commands.AddScript(
                    "Add-EsxSoftwareDepot -DepotUrl https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/PRODUCTION/main/vmw-depot-index.xml");

                IAsyncResult async = powerShell.BeginInvoke();
                while (async.IsCompleted == false)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("Working...");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("finish");
                if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                {//Here is output of Exception
                   Console.WriteLine(powerShell.Streams.Error[0].ToString());
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of Exception :

> The type initializer for 'VMware.ImageBuilder.Impl.IfServer' threw an exception.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see what exception is being thrown?

Comment: Have a look at the `InnerException` property of the exception - they may be more information about the underlying problem, and exactly where it occurred.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. The exception is actually raised from System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse, so maybe it is a network problem; however I'm unable to resolve this.